# How to insert a html element (JSX) to the DOM with content script in a React Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

First I want to say that a found some answers for my question, but they are too old and cannot help me.

I created a simple React app with intention to use it as a Chrome extension.

*Node.js v18.15.0* / *React 18.2.0*

```
npx create-react-app my-extension
```

I set the manifest as sugested by the Google [doc](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/).

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "Test.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I added a simple content script to insert a html element to the DOM everytime a page is loaded.

*Test.js*

```
var p = document.createElement("p")
p.innerText = "text"
var body = document.querySelector("body")
body.appendChild(p)
```

It works fine, but what I want is add to the DOM the element provided by a react component like this:

*Test.jsx*

```
function Test() {
    return (
        <p>text</p>
    )
}
export default Test
```

I cannot find a way to configure the environment to do the content script works with the react component.

Does anyone know how to do this or can suggest a solution? Grateful.

Answer (score 0):

To use a React component in a content script, you need to first transpile the JSX code to JavaScript using a tool like Babel. Then, you can include the transpiled JavaScript file in your content script.

Here's how you can do it:

1. Install the necessary dependencies:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-react
```

2. Create a `.babelrc` file in the root of your project with the following content:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

3. Create a new file `TestTranspiled.js` in the same directory as `Test.jsx` with the following content:

```
"use strict";

function Test() {
  return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("p", null, "text");
}

export default Test;
```

4. Transpile the `Test.jsx` file to `TestTranspiled.js` using the following command:

```
npx babel Test.jsx --out-file TestTranspiled.js
```

5. Include the `TestTranspiled.js` file in your `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "TestTranspiled.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, your content script should be able to use the `Test` component:

```
var p = document.createElement("p");
ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(Test, null), p);
var body = document.querySelector("body");
body.appendChild(p);
```

Note that you also need to include the `react` and `react-dom` libraries in your content script for this to work. You can do this by adding the following lines to your `Test.jsx` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
```